# Asus range extender slows down over time

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-extender

MY setup:
RT-N66R -> RT-N66R -> - RT-N12D1

Modes of each:

- RT-N66R #1: Router
- RT-N66R #2 Access point (MAC filter whitelist for only the single RT-N12D1)
- RT-N12D1 (Range extender mode, 69dB stable tx and rx)

The issue is in the wireless link between the RT-N66R -> - RT-N12D1. At first, the speed is a stable 50mbit/s. Sometimes I can transfer many GB before the connection breaks at this speed. Then randomly, the packet loss goes to 98-100%. Speeds drop to near zero or worse. Nothing will fix the speeds besides rebooting the RT-N12D1, which sometimes its impossible to even connect to. This is despite being the ONLY wireless device on it's channel (channel 2). There is only ONE other wireless router within a mile, and it is on channel 11. After reboot, the speeds are instantly back to 50mbit/s.. If I don't reboot it, then it stays between 1kbps and 1mbps (or worse) forever.

What could be causing this? Is it seems like a software issue, but I have tried changing every setting and nothing seems to improve it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would update the firmware on each of these devices to the newest firmware available.

Comment: They are all the latest! :*

Comment: You may need to try a different box for the RT-N12D1.  I avoid Range Extenders because performance may not be good (although not variable as you are seeing).  I put something like a Ubiquiti AP on an Ethernet connection  for better pertormance.

Comment: @John It is across a road so wire is no option :(

Comment: Try a different access point. You might need to use entry level commercial gear to get across the road.

Comment: @John It would be expected with 69db signal in both directions to have a good connection though, no? Any recommendation for a good repeater?

Comment: Ubiquiti makes good Wireless Mesh products and I think their product line includes models with good power and range. For the home side, I use here a Cisco RV340W router and it has very good power and range.